# Writing Test Code for Boolean Result

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I have been through Trailhead and read multiple references, but am still not getting passing tests. I'm sure I'm missing something simple and need assistance with writing a passing test for a method that returns a boolean value.

Here is the controller extension (method) I need to test.

```
public with sharing class ShouldShowMedSection{
    public ShouldShowMedSection(ApexPages.StandardController paramController) {
       Intake = paramController;}
    public ApexPages.StandardController Intake {get; set;}
    public Boolean getShouldShowMedSection() {
       Intake__c record = (Intake__c)Intake.getRecord();
        
        
          if(
            record.Personal_Care__c != null && record.Personal_Care__c.contains('Medication')
            ) 
            {
            return true;
            }
      
        
          return false;
        }
        
        }
```

Here is the test method I need assistance adjusting:

```
@isTest
public class IntakeExtensionTest {
    
    static testMethod void ShouldShowMedSection() {        
   
        Intake__c i1 = new Intake__c();
        Boolean isValid = false;
        
        Test.StartTest();
        
        i1.Client_Name_First_and_Last_Initial__c = 'Test Client A';
        i1.Personal_Care__c.contains('Medication');
        
        insert i1; 
        
        isValid = Intake__c.validate(i1);
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(isValid, true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the controller object first

```
ShouldShowMedSection ctrl = new ShouldShowMedSection(
     new ApexPages.StandardController(
       new Intake__c(Client_Name_First_and_Last_Initial__c = 'Test Client A',
                     Personal_Care__c = 'xxxMedicationxxx')));

System.assertEquals(true,ctrl. getShouldShowMedSection(),'sb valid');
```

Notes:

- The first argument of the assert should be the expected value, not the actual value - in your testmethod, you had them reversed
- In your controller, this clause `record.Personal_Care__c != null` can be removed because a standardcontroller will always have a record

The whole controller could be simplified/standardized to typical pattern to:

```
public with sharing class ShouldShowMedSection{
 ApexPages.StandardController ctrl;   
 public ShouldShowMedSection(ApexPages.StandardController ctrl) {
   this.ctrl = ctrl;
  }
 public Intake__c record {
    get {
     record = this.ctrl.getRecord();
     return record;
     } set; }      

 public Boolean getShouldShowMedSection() {
    return this.record.Personal_Care__c?.contains('Medication');
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so muchh